# Convert interface to struct

Tags: go

```
type SipField interface {
    Info() (id, name, defaultValue string, length int)
}

type Field string

func (f *Field) Get() string {
    return string(*f)
}

func (f *Field) Set(s string) {
    *f = Field(s)
}

type CommandID Field

func (cid *CommandID) Info() (id, name, defaultValue string, length int) {
    return "", "command ID", "", 2
}

type Language Field

func (l *Language) Info() (id, name, defaultValue string, length int) 
{
    return "", "language", "019", 3
}

func InitField(f interface{}, val string) error {
    sipField, ok := f.(SipField)
    if !ok {
        return errors.New("InitField: require a SipField")
    }
    _, _, defaultValue, length := sipField.Info()
    field, ok := f.(*Field)
    if !ok {
     return errors.New("InitField: require a *Field")
    }
    return nil
}
```

How should I do for converting `interface{}` to `Field(CommandID, Language...)` in `InitField()` function? I try to directly type assert by

```
field, ok := f.(*Field)
```

but it not working.I have tried to use unsafe.Pointer but failed also.

Comment: How exactly does it "not working"? What arguments do you call `InitField` with? Your program (minor issues notwithstanding) is syntactically correct and compiles. So the problem must be runtime, and you haven't provided the actual error.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/r0pgoNQJVgo but to me, the code looks like some sort of horrible overengineering. I'd recomment to post a message to the mailing list or to `/r/golang` on Reddit, clearly explain *the problem* (not your solution of it) and solicit for help.

Comment: You first need to type assert `f` to `*CommandID` and then you can *convert* that to `*Field` like so: `(*Field)(f.(*CommandID))`. Type assertion `x.(T)`, type conversion `T(x)`. See here: https://play.golang.org/p/m3gHdXRSig5

Comment: Why do you accept an empty interface in InitField if it can only work with SipField in the first place? And why does Info return strings when the third value must be a Field. None of this makes much sense to me.

Comment: @shakurov In fact, I want to implement inheriting with go, but it seems not possible.

Comment: @kostix It is only a experiment. I want to implement inheriting without composition. And now I understand it is not a correct way

Comment: @mkopriva I defined hundreds of Field, like CommandID, Language, PatronPassword..., and compose Request struct with them, so I can't check all type of them in one function except using switch type assert.

Comment: @Peter SipField is only a interface containing Info() function, I also want to store value in Field. In early I defined each Field as a struct, but it only has one field, for example 'type CommandID struct { Value string }', I want to make the definition easier and clearer, so the problem emerged.

Comment: @wangjun Why do you need to type assert each one of them, is it because you need to use `Get`/`Set`? If so you could do it this way: https://play.golang.org/p/neXAeKpFLy3

Comment: @mkopriva it looks like what I expecting

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Have a look at [Type assertions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) chapter in Go reference. It states:

> `x.(T)`
>
> More precisely, if T is not an interface type, x.(T) asserts that the dynamic type of x is identical to the type T.

Types CommandID and Field are not identical as described in [Type identity](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_identity).

> A defined type is always different from any other type.

Both types CommandId and Fields are defined as described in [Type definitions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_definitions).

> A type definition creates a new, distinct type with the same underlying type and operations as the given type, and binds an identifier to it.
>
> `TypeDef = identifier Type .`

You can only do

```
field, ok := f.(*CommandID)
```

or

```
field, ok := f.(*Language)
```

As @mkopriva mentioned in the comment, you can do type conversion later to `*Field` but this it does not seem to be your goal.

Other solution is to introduce a Field interface with Set and Get methods. Then you will need to provide an implementation for every implementing type.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and edition. I have read links you mentioned, it seems that I select a wrong direction at all. I will change my struct definition. By the way, is there another way to implement inheriting, except compose?

Comment: @wangjun No, the composition is the only way to do it.